# how to multiply 3 by 3 matrices using scala

Tags: scala

please find the code 
    object MatrixMul extends App {

```
val threedim = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
val threedimanother = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
val elements = for {
row <- threedim
ele <- row
} yield ele
for (i <- elements) {
println("the 3 dim array are " + i)
}
val elements1 = for {
row <- threedimanother
ele <- row
} yield ele
for (j <- elements1)
print("another 3 dim array  " + j)
def mult[A](a: [threedim] , b:[threedimanother])(implicit n :Numeric[A])={
for(row <- a)
  yield for(col <- b.transpose)
   yield row zip col map Function.tupled(_*_) reduceLeft(_+_) 
 }
 }
```

this code needs to mul the threedim * threedimanother

Comment: but i am gettting error can you pls guide me how to solve this

Comment: Also post the error, btw. this code is full of errors. First is `def mult[A](a: [threedim], …)`  is not valid. `threedim` is a value and not a type. Also I have no idea what the square brackets shall indicate. It must be `def mult[A](a: Array[Array[A]], b: Array[Array[A]])…`. You also might want to use `IndexedSeq` instead of arrow, as creating new `Arrays[A]` requires  a `ClassTag[A]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your implementation of the `mult` function if you change the signature as follows:

```
def mult(a: Array[Array[Int]], b: Array[Array[Int]]) : Array[Array[Int]] = {
  for(row <- a)
    yield for(col <- b.transpose)
      yield row zip col map Function.tupled(_*_) reduceLeft(_+_)
}
```

Comment: Hi aamir why did u take off the solution it was working fine

Comment: HI Harald Thanks for the solution